# subprocess not creating output file of ffmpeg command

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am trying to run an ffmpeg command that records my screen and creates an .mp4 file of the recording in python. The command works when I run it in my shell, but is not working when I am running it in a Python script using subprocess.

The issue is that when running it with subprocess, the output.mp4 file is not created.

Here is the command:
`timeout 10 ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -acodec aac -strict experimental output.mp4`

Here is the python code:

```
os.chdir('/home/user/Desktop/myProject/')

subprocess.run('timeout 5 ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -acodec aac -strict experimental out.mp4')
```

Is there an additional configuration to add so that subprocess can write output files?

Comment: You have a different `timeout` in the working example than in the failing one; if the command takes more than 5 seconds but less than 10, that's the explanation.

Comment: In your example, `ffmpeg` is completely responsible for writing the output file. You can easily add a `stdout` argument to `subprocess` to write to a file handle of your choice, but that is not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.run` returns an `CompletedProcess` object. You should assign that to a variable, and then print out all output and errors of the command (Because i think, ffmpeg gives an error and doesn't try to write the file at all, but you do not see that).
Additionally, you have to either set the keyword argument `shell` to True, or use `shlex.split`, else the command will not be formatted right. `shlex.split` is the preferred way, as you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows
> the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of
> arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names).

And you do not want to manually convert the string into a list of arguments !

And there is no need to stop ffmpeg from the outside (another reason why your file might not get written). Use the builtin command line [option `-t`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Main-options) for that.

```py
import shlex
import subprocess
import os

os.chdir('/home/user/Desktop/myProject/')

p = subprocess.run(shlex.split("ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -acodec aac -strict experimental -t 00:00:05 out.mp4"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(p.stdout)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `timeout` you may use the `-t` option as posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436956/stop-the-recording-after-some-period-of-time).

Add `-t 00:00:05` argument, and remove the `timeout`:

```
subprocess.run('ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -acodec aac -strict experimental -t 00:00:05 out.mp4')
```

I think it's more elegant to use command argument than using `timeout` for terminating the process.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, for hysterical reasons, you can pass in a single string without `shell=True` and it will work. For portable code, you need to either specify `shell=True`, or refactor the code to avoid it (which is [generally recommended wherever feasible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)).

Note also that `subprocess.run()` has keyword arguments both for setting a timeout and for specifying the working directory for the subprocess.

```py
subprocess.run(
    ['ffmpeg', '-video_size', '1920x1080', '-framerate', '60',
               '-f', 'x11grab', '-i', ':0.0+0,0', '-f', 'alsa',
               '-ac', '2', '-i', 'pulse', '-acodec', 'aac',
               '-strict', 'experimental', 'out.mp4'],
    cwd='/home/user/Desktop/myProject/',   # current working directory
    timeout=5,                             # timeout
    check=True                             # check for errors
    )
```

With `check=True` you will get an exception if the command fails, the timeout will raise an exception if the command times out, regardless of whether you have `check=True`.

Without more information about what failed, it's hard to specify how exactly to fix your problem; but with this, hopefully you should at least get enough information in error messages to guide you.